# Complex Combinatorics issue - 2 fruits, 3 folks.

Tags: combinatorics

OK, so I've got a pretty complex problem i'm having trouble with.

I need to divide *w* watermelons and *l* lemons among three people (Alex, Bart, Cody) with several requirements on the division (they can get 0 of a given fruit).

Cody must have more lemons than watermelons.
No person may have an equal number of lemons and watermelons.
Alex and Bart cannot both have more watermelons than lemons.

So i'm not strong in combinatorics.  I think i've got the first requirement down though:

for the *l* lemons there are (l+1)(l+2)/2 possible divisions, and for *w* watermelons (w+1)(w+2)/2.  Of these, I'm fairly sure that the number of divisions that are unusable because of the first condition is (w-l)(1+w-l)/2.

First I suppose my question is whether or not I'm thinking about the first condition correctly.

Second, how do I factor in the other conditions?

Comment: Consider first the case where either Bart or Alex has more watermelons than lemons, then consider the case where none of them do.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure how to get there with _two_ sets of partitioned fruit.  Within the subset of results where Cody has more lemons than watermelons, there's obviously a subset where Bart has more watermelons than lemons but alex doesn't, one where Alex does but Bart doesn't, one where neither do, and one where both do.  Of those, only the first two fit in the rules.  But once I narrow down the number of results to the first parameter, I'm just not able to make the next step. =/